# plot piechart for a column in pandas dataframe by grouping a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

This question is relevant to my previous question.

I would like to plot a column of a pandas dataframe so that I can draw a pie chart in matplotlib.

The dataframe (my_df):

```
  name   value 
  cscas   15   
  wfdce   17   
  ynvas   22   
  rebdf   36   
  dgref   16    
  ytjvs   26      
  qtvsa   39      
  wvwev   32
```

I need to add a new column to mark the value belong to a group, 
e.g. my_df:

```
  name   value value_group
  cscas   15   [10, 19]
  wfdce   17   [10, 19]
  ynvas   22   [20, 29]
  rebdf   36   [30, 39]
  dgref   16   [10, 19] 
  ytjvs   26   [20, 29]   
  qtvsa   39   [30, 39]   
  wvwev   32   [30, 39]
```

I need to use the value_group to do a "group by" so that I can show the number of "names" as a percentage in a pie chart.

```
 [10, 19]  2
 [30, 39]  3
 ....
```

I used :

```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  my_df['value_group'] = ((my_df['value']//10 * 10).astype('string') , (self.__df['value']//10 + 1) * 10 - 1).astype('string'))

  new_df = my_df.groupby(['value_group'])['name'].size()

  ax.pie(new_df.values, labels = [x for x in new_df.keys()], autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow = False, startangle = 90)
```

But, it does not work.

How to change the query ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
my_df['value_group'] = pd.cut(my_df['value'], range(0, 50, 10), right=False)

new_df = my_df.groupby('value_group').agg({'name': 'count'})
new_df.plot.pie(y='value', figsize=(6, 6), autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow = False, startangle = 90)
```

Comment: thanks, but, how to create and add the new column of "value_group"?